# Which is better - Copying in S3 or downloading and uploading from S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am writing a piece of code in which files on S3 need to be copied. What will be a better process for it - copying the files withing S3 itself or downloading the file and uploading them? I have no use of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you requirement is to copy an object in Amazon S3 to another location in Amazon S3 (even if it is in a different bucket or different region), it is always better to issue a Copy command. This way, the transfer happens totally within Amazon S3 and there are less chances of problems.

For example, data can be copied by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/foo.txt s3://destination-bucket/foo.txt
```

This will copy an object between buckets without downloading the file.